# Getting data from a TextField in a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, textfield

I created a nib with a TabelViewCell which contains a label and a TextField, then I'm loading this cell in a TableView with just two rows. I want to capture the name of an item and it's price, so I updated each label in cellForRowAtIndexPath method since I can have access to the indexPath.row value.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleCellIdentifier = @"AddBudgetItemCell";

    SCAddBudgetItemCell *cell = (SCAddBudgetItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleCellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:simpleCellIdentifier owner:self options:nil];

        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.dataTextField.delegate = self;

    switch (indexPath.row)
    {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Item";
            break;

        case 1:
            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Price ¥";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

However I don't know how I can retrieve the data from the TextField's since I don't have access to either the variable "cell" I created nor the IndexPath.row value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it you have two options. If Inside your `SCAddBudgetItemCell` you have a property containing the string of the textfield then probably you can access it from your viewcontroller by doing something like `cell.yourtextfield.text` (where yourtexfield is the UITextView inside your SCAddBudgetItemCell.

The other option is to make the view controller respond to the UITextFieldDelegate and store the string as the user edits it by implementing the delegate methods

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    //Whenever people start editing your textfield
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     //
return YES;
}
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    //This is obvious. Whenever they end
}
```